# simple_form no input found for json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql, simple-form

Environment
Mac OS X
Rails 4.0.4
Ruby 2.1.1

Gems:
[simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple%5fform)

Create a model with a json typed field, here my migration file:

```
create_table :my_model do |t|
  t.string :name
  t.json :my_field

  t.timestamps
end
```

And now when I try to create a New object (New form), I am getting this error

```
RuntimeError - No input found for json:
  simple_form (3.0.2) lib/simple_form/form_builder.rb:551:in `find_mapping'
  simple_form (3.0.2) lib/simple_form/form_builder.rb:482:in `find_input'
  simple_form (3.0.2) lib/simple_form/form_builder.rb:111:in `input'
```

I am guessing that simple_form is not handling the JSON type very well, and I really don't know how to work around this one (newbie with simple_form).

Hope you can help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

simple_form, doesn't support `JSON` type natively. but as it turns out, JSON is text based data format, you can simple use textarea to output json.

```
<%= f.my_field, as: :text %>
```

this should work fine

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget the comma, `<%= f.input, as: :text %>`

Answer (score 0):

You can also put following line in the initializer to define custom input mappings.

```
SimpleForm::FormBuilder.map_type :json, to: SimpleForm::Inputs::TextInput
```